# Shouldn't my insurance cover my trip interruption?

Tags: usa, air-travel, travel-insurance-claim

I was scheduled to fly on Delta flight 489 out of JFK on August 11th and, after sitting on the tarmac for 8 hours, the flight was cancelled due to weather conditions. No other flights were available that evening. I had to book a flight out of Logan in Boston the next day on Jet Blue.

I lost one day at the resort and the insurance I purchased states *inclement weather that causes complete cessation of service for at least 12 hours is covered under Trip Interruptions. It covers Trip cost.*

I am trying to recoup the cost for the one day lost at the resort but Trip Mate says it is a missed connection, which is only covered for a maximum of $500 which was paid for the flight.

From what I have explained, shouldn't this have been covered?

They only offered $500 for a missed connection. The original flight was with Delta but I had to rebook with Jet Blue.

Comment: Can you clarify the offer? Did they offer you USD 500 in addition to the extra flight, or just the flight cost, or nothing at all?

Comment: How does the insurance policy define "Trip cost?"

Comment: There's more here you're not telling us.  Why did you have to book a new flight?  If your flight was delayed, the airline would have put you on a later flight. 
 - why did you not do this?  Did you have multiple flights, on multiple separate tickets?

Comment: There were no other flights available on the day we we to fly on Delta on Saturday August 11th. Our flight was canceled after 8 hours on the tarmac. Since I had paid for a week at a resort in Punta Cana and I felt the only option was to get a flight out of Boston.

Comment: Under Trip Mate policy F409N Schedule Of Benefits Trip Interruptions the benefit amount is the Trip Cost. Under this category they would pay. They claim the cancellation is covered under Missed Connection which only pays a max of $500 which I used to book a new flight.

Comment: Although this is travel related insurance the issue boils down to the interpretation of the contract. You can claim all you like, and you might be right, but if the insurance company digs it's heels in it will take the services of a lawyer to make them pay. Is the benefit to you of payment for one day's holiday worth the grief and risk in legal costs?

Comment: What you might be owed by the insurance company will be (or should be) determined by the policy terms. Without reading the actual wording of the policy — not your summary  — one can't say what's covered and what isn't.

Comment: OP not returned to clarify, putting on hold